# How to write a GET request in angular

Tags: angular

I want to retrieve data from a api call which will return the server timezone details. This is the url I want to hit: `https://10.77.44.104/webrtmt/rest/logcollection/getTimeZone`

And the data is in this format when I currently open the link :

```
{
  "TimeZone" : {
    "Mode" : {
      "name" : "Mode",
      "value" : "Standard"
    },
    "LocalTimeZone" : {
      "name" : "LocalTimeZone",
      "value" : "(GMT+5:30)India Standard Time-Asia/Kolkata"
    }
  }
}
```

So, what I want is to send a server name which will return the timezone for that specific server name. I am not able to figure out how to write the get request for fetching the details. Someone please help. I am totally new to api integration.

Comment: Check this: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-http-get-example-using-httpclient/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute a HTTP GET request for your Web API on the following URI in Angular:

```
https://10.77.44.104/webrtmt/rest/logcollection/getTimeZone
```

Create an API service class and add a method that calls your HTTP GET method as shown:

```
getTimeZone(serverName)
{
    return this.http.get('https://10.77.44.104/webrtmt/rest/logcollection/getTimeZone/' + serverName); 
}
```

(You will need to include the HTTP library as shown:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'
```

)

Then in your Angular component subscribe to the API service like this:

```
timeZone: any; 

...   

ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getTimeZone().subscribe(res => {
        this.timeZone = res
        console.log("reading timezone from API");
    })
}
```

The object timeZone in your component will store your time zone object with the keys "TimeZone", "LocalTimeZone" and the respective name/value pairs.

Try that and see how it goes.